# How do I check if the array does not exist into a <tr> - vuejs

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

My back-end service return the json array only when it has values and when it doesn't I got the error in my front-end -

> "[Vue warn]: Error in render: "TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of
>   undefined"

I don't know how to list the values only when the array exists, I'm new with front-end development and trying to build it with `Vue.Js`  and *Vuetify*...

-> I need to get the Array's first position because besides it is an array it always return only one item.

***Front-end***

```
  <v-data-table :headers="headers" :items="items" :search="search" sort-by="id" class="elevation-1">
    <template v-slot:item="{item}">
        <tr>
          <td class="d-block d-sm-table-cell">{{ item.name }}</td>
          <td class="d-block d-sm-table-cell">{{item.myArray[0].prop1}}</td>
          ...
```

***back-end Json***

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "John",
        "myArray": [
            {
                "prop1": "341",
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "nome": "22222"
    }
```

Comment: always check if there is some sort of nullness.  `v-if="item && item.myArray"` for example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check if `item` and `item.myArray` is not undefined and `item.myArray` have elements.

Try:

```
<td v-if='item && item.myArray && item.myArray.length' class="d-block d-sm-table-cell">{{item.myArray[0].prop1}}</td>
```

Try in CodePen:
https://codepen.io/gborchardt/pen/WNvezWg

Comment: This answer is correct in case there shouldn't be a <td> at all if the array doesn't exist. In case you want to render a <td> with no value, you can move the `item && item.myArray && item.myArray.length && item.myArray[0].prop1` between {{ }}. Yet it would be nicer to move it to a computed value in that case.

Comment: Thanks  for your answer @Frankly, I haven't figured out how I can move the v-f into the <td>, It didn't work for me.

Comment: Thanks @Kielstra, how can I do it with computed value ? thanks

Comment: @BrunoDZ Show how you tried. I added an example at: https://codepen.io/gborchardt/pen/WNvezWg

Comment: thanks a lot @frankly ! I used the v-if as you said with a v-else in case there is no the array item. it worked fine for me.                  

`<td v-if="item && item.myArray && item.myArray.length" class="d-block d-sm-table-cell">{{item.myArray[0].prop1}}</td>`

`<td v-else class="d-block d-sm-table-cell"></td>`